# Преобразовать многомерный массив в другой многомерный | PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
$array = [
    [
        'code' => '001',
        'name' => 'Prostite',
        'whpr' => [
            'wh_price_rest' => [
                ['price' => 255, 'wrh' => 1],
                ['price'=> 900, 'wrh' => 5]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'code' => '002',
        'name' => 'Menya',
        'whpr' => [
            'wh_price_rest' => [
                ['price' => 34535, 'wrh' => 42],
                ['price'=> 5445, 'wrh' => 2432]
            ]
        ]
    ],
];
```

Как преобразовать этот массив по ключу `whpr`, чтобы массивы `whpr` стали новыми элементами своего массива?

Т.е. в данном случае, чтобы из этого массива получилось не два, а четыре:

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [code] => 001 [name] => Prostite [price] => 255 [wrh] => 1) 
[1] => Array ( [code] => 001 [name] => Prostite [price] => 900 [wrh] => 5) 
[2] => Array ( [code] => 002 [name] => Menya [price] => 34535 [wrh] => 42) 
[3] => Array ( [code] => 002 [name] => Menya [price] => 5445[wrh] => 2432) 
)
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имеем многомерный массив:

```
$array = [
    [
        'code' => '001',
        'name' => 'Prostite',
        'whpr' => [
            'wh_price_rest' => [
                ['price' => 255, 'wrh' => 1],
                ['price'=> 900, 'wrh' => 5]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'code' => '002',
        'name' => 'Menya',
        'whpr' => [
            'wh_price_rest' => [
                ['price' => 34535, 'wrh' => 42],
                ['price'=> 5445, 'wrh' => 2432]
            ]
        ]
    ],
];
```

Преобразовываем в нужны вид:

```
$result = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    foreach ($item['whpr']['wh_price_rest'] as $key => $value) {
        unset($item['whpr']);
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) $item[$k] = $v;
        $result[] = $item;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/2GXOI

Comment: Супер, спасибо!